# Movement of an object in a two frame

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I look forward to your help.
I try to calculate the movement of a certain item between frame and frame. I use a camera with depth.
I want to know the depth change for a pixel (x, y) from the previous frame to the current frame but the item may be moving and I need to adjust the pixel (x, y) before.

Things I've done:

1. I have 2 frames with contours previous and current.-Attached
2. I know how to take the depth in a pixel (x, y)

I want to get an idea of how to calculate the pixel offset (x, y)

previous:

[image]

current:

[image]

Comment: Are those actual input images, or do you have noise in your image?

Comment: Get the Corners of this contour and track it using [Lukas-Kanade optical flow](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/dc/d6b/group__video__track.html#ga473e4b886d0bcc6b65831eb88ed93323). Since you have the depth, you can determine the 3D velocities

Comment: @Gopiraj Hi Gopiraj Thank you very much for your response.
I'm not sure I need the speed. I need the mapping of the pixels.
That is, if I check the depth of a pixel in the previous image, it will match what is in the current image.

Comment: @Timo , Hi First of all thank you very much for the response. These are real images after I do an image processing.. I'll try to explain better, someone is supposed to put something in the box. And I have to identify where he goes in - here comes the subject of depth. The thing is that the box moves after you put something in, and so the box is placed differently in the "now" frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try feature matching (using something like SIFT or [ORB](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_orb/py_orb.html) could work).

You can also try to utilize the [ICP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_closest_point) algorithm. Get the contours of both images and store all the points of those contours in separate containers (like `cv::Mat` or `std::vector<cv::Point>`). Use one vector as source cloud of the ICP and the other vector as query cloud. You can find an implementation of ICP [here](http://www.morethantechnical.com/2010/06/06/iterative-closest-point-icp-with-opencv-w-code/) (or use a 3rd party library, like [PCL](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl)). The ICP algorithm then gives you an approximated transformation that best matches the clouds. This is the transformation that you are looking for.

Comment: thank you very much, I'll try to do it and keep you updated.